# Debian stretch: Kernel panic hangs Gnome desktop

Tags: debian, pulseaudio

I was listening to music via PulseAudio when completely out of the blue, desktop suddenly froze with no mouse/keyboard response.  Checking syslog around the time of the incident shows loads and loads of lines like this:

```
Dec 15 21:25:58 lamb-biryani-jme tracker-miner-f[1378]:   (Sparql buffer) Error in task 0 (file:///home/jamesmeast/Music/all/Fever%20Ray) of the array-update: UNIQUE constraint failed: nie:DataObject.nie:url (strerror of errno (not necessarily related): No such file or directory)
Dec 15 21:25:58 lamb-biryani-jme tracker-miner-f[1378]: Could not execute sparql: UNIQUE constraint failed: nie:DataObject.nie:url (strerror of errno (not necessarily related): No such file or directory)
Dec 15 21:25:58 lamb-biryani-jme tracker-miner-f[1378]:   (Sparql buffer) Error in task 1 (file:///home/jamesmeast/Music/all/Feeder) of the array-update: UNIQUE constraint failed: nie:DataObject.nie:url (strerror of errno (not necessarily related): No such file or directory)
Dec 15 21:25:58 lamb-biryani-jme tracker-miner-f[1378]: Could not execute sparql: UNIQUE constraint failed: nie:DataObject.nie:url (strerror of errno (not necessarily related): No such file or directory)
```

Working my way back up syslog, I see the following segfault:

```
Dec 15 21:24:46 lamb-biryani-jme kernel: [  129.201128] python[1394]: segfault at 10 ip 000056131ab4916f sp 00007ffd13af4450 error 4 in python2.7[56131a9dc000+322000]
Dec 15 21:24:59 lamb-biryani-jme pulseaudio[1273]: [pulseaudio] bluez5-util.c: GetManagedObjects() failed: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.TimedOut: Failed to activate service 'org.bluez': timed out
```

I suspect the segfault in python and the pulsaudio timeout are related.  What is interesting is that, although the desktop was frozen at the time, music continued to play via pulseaudio.

My uname -a output:

```
Linux lamb-biryani-jme 4.9.0-8-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.9.130-2 (2018-10-27) x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe I have tracked down what the issue is.

A few lines further up from the segfault was a warning line from `hplip-systray`, the system tray app for an HP Printer:

```
Dec 15 21:24:46 lamb-biryani-jme hplip-systray.desktop[1394]: /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gtk-2.0/gtk/__init__.py:127: RuntimeWarning: PyOS_InputHook is not available for interactive use of PyGTK
```

I had recently bought a new HP Printer and had installed `hplip` for it. A similar segfault also occurred a month later, and syslog quoted the same above error from `hplip-systray`.

I therefore disabled the system tray app by removing the file `hplip-systray.desktop` from the directory `/etc/xdg/autostart` (I have Gnome as my desktop), and restarting the system.  This prevented `hplip-systray` from starting up in the first place, and I verified this on my system after reboot by running `ps -ef | grep hplip-systray`.

Since then, I have had no segfaults occurring, and system remains stable.